# Is there a MIME type for Python wheels (.whl)?

Tags: python, python-wheel

Is there a (de facto) standard MIME type to use for Python wheel packages? I couldn't see any in PEP 427.

I suppose application/zip could be an option, but that seems misleading to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. However, we can artificially construct one of the following:

- `application/x-wheel+zip`
- `application/x-pywheel+zip`

Comment: @AlphaMycelium Thank you for fixing my spelling, grammar and formatting! English is not my native language.